# I need help mapping user details to a user class in my Grails app using spring security core and spring security ldap

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, ldap

I am building a web app in which users will be authenticated against our ldap database, but the app itself will not hold a database of users, so all details except for roles will come from the ldap. With much struggle, I've gotten my app to connect to the database and authenticate, but I cannot get any of the user details to map to the principal.

My Config.groovy contains the following:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'OU=***,DC=***,DC=***'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter = "(sAMAccountName={0})"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.mapper.userDetailsClass = '<pack.age>.award.MyUserDetails'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDN = 'CN=***,OU=*** ,DC=***,dc=***'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = '[redacted]'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldaps://server:port'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = ['mail', 'displayName']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider'].
```

MyUserDetails.groovy:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

class MyUserDetails extends User {

   // extra instance variables
   final String fullname
   final String email



   MyUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
         boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, boolean passwordNonExpired, String fullname,
         String email, Collection authorities) {


      super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, 
         credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, passwordNonExpired, authorities)

      println "test";

      this.fullname = fullname
      this.email = email
   }
}
```

MyUserDetailsContextMapper.groovy:

```
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.UserDetailsContextMapper

import edu.bellevue.award.MyUserDetails

class MyUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

   UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
                                  Collection authorities) {

      String fullname = ctx.originalAttrs.attrs['cn'].values[0]
      String email = ctx.originalAttrs.attrs['mail'].values[0].toString().toLowerCase()

      def userDetails = new MyUserDetails(username, '', true, true, true, true, true,
                        fullname, email)

      return userDetails
   }

   void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Only retrieving data from AD is currently supported")
   }
}
```

Going through all the log messages, I can see that my app is connecting to the database and authenticating, but if I try something like printing out the principal (with just a println or log.info), it just says anonymousUser. I don't know if it's related, but I am getting a few exceptions thrown at me.

```
| Error 2014-02-12 15:43:25,630 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR [/award].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/award] threw exception
Message: No signature of method: static java.lang.Math.max() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, null) values: [4, null]
Possible solutions: max(int, int), max(double, double), max(float, float), max(long, long), min(int, int), wait()
    Line | Method
->>  251 | doAppend              in org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton
```

And also:

```
AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /grails-errorhandler]
2014-02-12 15:43:25,720 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
Message: Access is denied
    Line | Method
->>   47 | decide    in grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager
```